# Unknown entries in the default /etc/postfix/aliases file

Tags: email, postfix

While setting up a new [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) installation on a Mageia 3 Linux system, I came upon a few entries in the default `/etc/postfix/aliases` file that I do not know the background of:

```
# Common aliases for system accounts.
...
foo:            root
falken:         root

# traps to catch security attacks
...
moof:           root
moog:           root
```

None of these aliases exists in the `aliases` file included in the Postfix source code distribution and I was unable to find any concrete reference to justify their existence.

1. Does anyone know why these aliases may have been included? Is there perhaps some interesting historical background?
2. Considering that I do not intend to have people send mail to `root` through any of these aliases, do they actually offer any sort of functionality in some other scenario? Or are they just noise to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`falken` is most likely a reference to the incredibly crappy 1983 movie [War Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames).  I'll probably get voted down for saying that because a lot of people like that movie, but it was just dumb.  Worse, it set the standard for how hacker movies were supposed to look.  OTOH I couldn't stand the movie back then...but i'd probably be amused by it today.

`moof` is probably a reference to the Apple [dogcow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogcow), which was a popular in-joke in Mac programming circles in the mid-1980s.  I recall references to the dogcow in Apple Tech Notes of that era, and maybe also in the Macintosh Programmer's Workshop (MPW) documentation.

It's hard to be believe it now, but once upon a time, Apple used to be a company full of hackers and geeks.

I don't know about `moog` - maybe someone at Mageia likes early analog synthesizers?

The aliases can almost certainly be deleted or commented out without causing any problems.  They're probably just a joke.